# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate method not called in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created a custom transition animation for a modal view controller by implementing the methods in the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol.

In iOS 8 and 9 the methods are called normally and the transition works. However, in iOS 7, the `animationControllerForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController:` method never gets called. The `animationControllerForDismissedController:` method still gets called normally.

```
#import "MyModalTransitioningDelegate.h"
#import "MyModalFadeTransition.h"

@implementation MyModalTransitioningDelegate

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                  presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                      sourceController:(UIViewController *)source
{
    return [[MyModalFadeTransition alloc] init];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
    return [[MyModalFadeTransition alloc] init];
}

@end
```

In the modal view controller (i.e. the "presented controller") I have the following in its `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.modalTransitionDelegate = [[OTModalTransitioningDelegate alloc] init]; // This is a custom strong private property due to `tranisitioningDelegate` being a weak property.
self.transitioningDelegate = self.modalTransitionDelegate;
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

Setting the `modalPresentationStyle` doesn't seem to make any difference in any version of iOS. The method that isn't being called does say that it's available in iOS 7 so I'm not sure why it isn't being called.

The modal view controller is being presented with the following code in the presenting view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:self.modalViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `transitioningDelegate` in the presenting view controller's initialiser instead of the `viewDidLoad` method fixed the issue.

It appears in iOS 7 a view controller's transitioning logic is called before `viewDidLoad`, but is the other way around from iOS 8 onwards.

Answer (score 55):

If anyone comes across this in later years, and you're using Swift 3, make sure that your call **isn't** to "`animationControllerForPresentedController`".

As of Xcode 8.1, the compiler doesn't automatically recognize this problem and thus doesn't offer to convert the code to modern syntax.

The above code will compile but it won't be a protocol implementation. It will just be a **custom**, uncalled function. (Such are the hazards of optional protocol methods, and the myriad problems with Xcode's autocomplete.)

So, make sure you implement the protocol with Swift 3 syntax:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
        presenting: UIViewController,
        source: UIViewController)
        -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    // ... return your cached controller object here.
}
```

And remember to set the presentation style on the View Controller to be presented:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
```

And the delegate:

```
self.transitioningDelegate = self // or wherever
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Why on earth doesn't Xcode suggest that the original method is wrong.

Comment: Same problem in Swift 4. Nice catch. Thanks

Comment: Just migrated a Swift 1 project to Swift 5. Your answer saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Another issue is that [`transitioningDelegate` is a *weak property*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621421-transitioningdelegate). So you can assign to it, then have your transitioning delegate class be **released** before the transition has a chance to run. When the transition *does* run, the value of `transitioningDelegate` is `nil`, and your methods never get called.

To see this, do the following:

```
let myVC = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
likesVC.transitioningDelegate = BackgroundFadesInPresentationDelegate(viewController: likesVC)
likesVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(likesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in your transition delegate class, add

```
deinit {
    print("deinit")
}
```

And see if that print statement is hit before the transition.

You will run into this problem if you use a freestanding class to implement the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.  This is why tutorials such as [this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions) generally have you implement the transitioning delegate in the either in the view controller class itself or as an extension. Other things are keeping the view controller from getting released.

In general in Cocoa Touch anything named "...Delegate" will be a weak property, to help avoid retain cycles. You should make your own custom class delegate properties weak as well. There's a good section on this in Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: In the second code block of my question you'll see I've covered this, I've got a custom strong property to hold a reference to my transition delegate. However this is something that could trip others up, so thanks for the contribution. :)

Comment: I'm having the above problem (in iOS 11). My transitioningDelegate is definitely NOT being released, and my modalPresentationStyle IS set to .custom. Stranger still, the "animationController" functions in my delegate DO get called. It's just complete insanity... Any idea where else to look?

Comment: Also, logging from within animationController(forPresented...) indicates that the transitioningDelegate and modalTransitionStyle are correct (or at least, they're what I would expect—i.e., my delegate class and "4" or ".custom").

Answer (score 0):

After digging, I found that my transitioningDelegate methods were not getting called because they were implemented in a protocol extension and the delegate methods must be @objc which is not supported in protocol extensions.
My resolution was to move this into the concrete class and add the @objc tag

```
    @objc func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        ...


    }
    
    // interaction for dismissing from  view
    @objc func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
   ...   
   }
```