# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a custom popup with custom transitions, but my delegate methods are not being called at all. This is my transitioning delegate:

```
public final class ModalTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    public func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        let controller = ModalPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)

        return controller
    }

    public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ModalAnimationPresenter()
    }

    public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ModalAnimationDissmiser()
    }
}
```

This is my popup view controller:

```
class StopWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {

        let transitioner = ModalTransitioningDelegate()
        modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        transitioningDelegate = transitioner
    }
}
```

This is how I present the popup:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
    let popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Popups", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! StopWorkoutViewController
    present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And this is the view controller in IB:

[image: Popup ViewController]

The popup is presented, but full-screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong

```
 func commonInit() {

        let transitioner = ModalTransitioningDelegate()
        modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        transitioningDelegate = transitioner
    }
```

Since you are going to animate the transition of `StopWorkoutViewController`.You need to set the transition delegate as

```
 @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
    let transitioner = ModalTransitioningDelegate()
    let popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Popups", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! StopWorkoutViewController
    popup.transitioningDelegate = transitioner
    present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I make this mistake every time. You have to set the transitioningDelegate on the view controller being presented, not the current view controller that's doing the presenting.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `transitioningDelegate` is a weak property, so the class you assign to it is getting released before the transition has a chance to run. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622538/1161906) for an example of how to catch this in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was about present(_:animated:) and dismiss(animated:completion:) methods called with animated set to false